# start and Stop Multiple tomcat with bash shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tomcat, sh

I wrote this sh script to stop and start multiple tomcat with this command on ubuntu terminal

```
sh apacheStopStartScript.sh start.
```

By starting this script the logs file are created there where my apacheStopStartScript.sh script is placed but I want the logs will created in there respective tomcat's bin/logs folder.

Any One resolve this issue?

```
#!/bin/bash
# script Name: apacheStopStartScript.sh
# Script is run by command: sh apacheStopStartScript.sh start
### END INIT INFO
TOMCATNAME=""
TOMCATCOMMANPATH="/root/siteforge/"
TOMCATFIRST="apache-two-siteforge"
TOMCATSECOND="apache-three-siteforge"
TOMCATTHIRD="apache-four-siteforge"
TOMCATFOURTH="apache-five-siteforge"
TOMCATFIFTH="apache-six-siteforge"
NOW=""
LOG=""
check=""
count=0
# This Function Is Used To Find Running Tomcat Process Id
tomcat_pid() {
   echo `ps -efa | grep $TOMCATNAME | grep tomcat | grep java | egrep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`
}

# This Function Is Used To Run/Start TOMCAT
start() {
    pid=$(tomcat_pid)
    if [ -n "$pid" ]
    then
        echo "TOMCAT : $TOMCATNAME is already running with (processId: $pid)"
    else     
        echo `nohup $TOMCATCOMMANPATH$TOMCATNAME/bin/catalina.sh run>>$LOG &`
        #   echo `nohup catalina.sh run>>logs/today.log &`      
        echo  "\n"
        check=$(cat $LOG | grep "Server startup in" | wc |tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 4)
        while [ $check -eq $count ]
        do
            echo "Starting TOMCAT : $TOMCATNAME "
            check_count=$(cat $LOG | grep "Server startup in" | wc |tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 4)
            check=`expr $check + $check_count `
            sleep 25
                if [ $check -gt $count ]
                then
                break
                fi
        done
        cat $LOG
        echo  "\n -------------------------TOMCAT :$TOMCATNAME STARTED SUCCESSFULLY----------------------------"
        echo "\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
        echo `ps -efa | grep tomcat`
    fi
    return 0
}

# This Function Is Used To Stop TOMCAT 
stop() {
    pid=$(tomcat_pid)
    if [ -n "$pid" ]
    then
        echo "Killing TOMCAT : $TOMCATNAME processes with (processId: $pid)"
        kill -9 $(tomcat_pid)  
        echo "\n -------------------------STOPPED TOMCAT :$TOMCATNAME ---------------------------------------" 
    else
        echo "TOMCAT : $TOMCATNAME is not running"
    fi
return 0 
}

# This Function Is Used To terminate/kill running Tomcat by process Id
terminate() {
    pid=$(tomcat_pid)
    if [ -n "$pid" ]
    then
        echo "Killing processes with (processId: $pid)"
        kill -9 $(tomcat_pid)  
    else
        echo "No Such Process Is Running"
    fi

    return 0
}

# These are calling function name i.e start, stop, restart,kill,status 
case $1 in
    start)

        TOMCATNAME=$TOMCATFIRST
        NOW="$(date +'%Y-%m-%d-%T')"
        LOG="$TOMCATCOMMANPATH$TOMCATNAME/bin/logs/$NOW.log"
        stop
        sleep 10
        start

        read -p "Are you sure you want to start $TOMCATSECOND? <Y/N> " prompt1
        case $prompt1 in
        [Yy]*)
            TOMCATNAME=$TOMCATSECOND
            NOW="$(date +'%Y-%m-%d-%T')"
            LOG="$TOMCATCOMMANPATH$TOMCATNAME/bin/logs/$NOW.log"
            stop
            sleep 10
            start 
        ;;
        [Nn]*)
         echo "Successfully Exit"
         exit;;
         esac

            TOMCATNAME=$TOMCATTHIRD
            NOW="$(date +'%Y-%m-%d-%T')"
            LOG="$TOMCATCOMMANPATH$TOMCATNAME/bin/logs/$NOW.log"
            stop
            sleep 10
            start 

            TOMCATNAME=$TOMCATFOURTH
            NOW="$(date +'%Y-%m-%d-%T')"
            LOG="$TOMCATCOMMANPATH$TOMCATNAME/bin/logs/$NOW.log"
            stop
            sleep 10
            start 

            TOMCATNAME=$TOMCATFIFTH
            NOW="$(date +'%Y-%m-%d-%T')"
            LOG="$TOMCATCOMMANPATH$TOMCATNAME/bin/logs/$NOW.log"
            stop
            sleep 10
            start 
        ;;
    stop)
        stop
        ;;
    restart)
        stop
        start
        ;;
     kill)
        terminate
    ;; 
    status)
       pid=$(tomcat_pid)
        if [ -n "$pid" ]
        then
           echo "TOMCAT : $TOMCATNAME is running with processId: $pid"
        else
           echo "TOMCAT : $TOMCATNAME is not running"
        fi
        ;;
esac 
exit 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally you can make your life easier by referring to catalina.sh to stop/start your tomcat for you:

so in your start process:

```
su - $TOMCAT_USER -c "$TOMCAT_PATH/catalina.sh start"
```

within catalina.sh you will see:

```
if [ -z "$CATALINA_OUT" ] ; then
  CATALINA_OUT="$CATALINA_BASE"/logs/catalina.out
fi
```

here is an example:

https://gist.github.com/miglen/5590986